# How can I return back values to parent component?

Tags: reactjs

I am using a component inside a component. It is well know that how to send data to child component. But how can I return back values from the child component to the parent component? I read `componentDidMount`, `componentWillMount`, but I am still confused in understanding how can I return back values to parent component from child component.

In my following code, please help me to return back a value from the child Catalog.jsx to the Parent component AppWrapper.jsx. Such that, I want to to return back from the function `ProductButtonClicked` at Catalog.jsx the *state value* `number_ofItems` to AppWrapper.jsx *state value* `itemsAdded`

Note: At AppWrapper.jsx, there is

Here is my Catalog.jsx file

```js
var React = require('react');
var Parse = require('parse').Parse;
var ParseReact = require('parse-react');
var cookie = require('react-cookie');

var Catalog = React.createClass({
mixins: [ParseReact.Mixin],

getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    // if the cookie is there, It will return the cookie value which I saved as 'true' word.
    FTWVeyCc4o: cookie.load('RahlTradingProductID-FTWVeyCc4o'),
    aJ3DoJp352: cookie.load('RahlTradingProductID-aJ3DoJp352'),
    dgeRhSG21U: cookie.load('RahlTradingProductID-dgeRhSG21U'),
    number_ofItems: 0
  };
},

componentDidMount: function() {
this.noOfItemsAdded();
 },


//Observe Function - a newly proposed function for prarse react integration
observe: function() {
  //declare any variable you need here.

  return {
    product: (new Parse.Query('product'))
              .ascending('createdAt')
  };
},

  //Render
  render: function() {

    var content = (
      <div>
        no product
      </div>
    );

    if(this.data.product.length){
      var content = (
        <div>
          { // Products are listed in this
                              this.data.product.map(function(p) {

                                return (
                                // <div>man</div>

                                  //From Design
                                  <div className="col-md-4">

                                      <div className="item text-center">

                                          <div className="photo">

                                              <img src={  p.productImgUrl }  />
                                              <br /><br />
                                              <h5>{p.name} <br /> {p.size}</h5>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                          <div className="action">
                                              <button
                                                type="button"
                                                className={"btn btn-"
                                                  + (
                                                        (this.state.FTWVeyCc4o && (p.objectId == "FTWVeyCc4o")) || (this.state.aJ3DoJp352 && (p.objectId == "aJ3DoJp352")) || (this.state.dgeRhSG21U && (p.objectId == "dgeRhSG21U")) ? 'warning' : 'primary'
                                                    )}

                                                onClick={this.ProductButtonClicked.bind(this, p)}
                                                >
                                                {(
                                                  (this.state.FTWVeyCc4o && (p.objectId == "FTWVeyCc4o")) || (this.state.aJ3DoJp352 && (p.objectId == "aJ3DoJp352")) || (this.state.dgeRhSG21U && (p.objectId == "dgeRhSG21U")) ? 'Remove' : 'Add'
                                                )}
                                              </button>
                                              
                                          </div>


                                  </div>
                                );
                            }, this)}


        </div>

      );

    }
    else{
      var content = (<div>

      </div>);
      }
    return <div>{content}</div>;
  },

  ProductButtonClicked:function(obj){
    //alert(this.incrementCount())
    // a = this.state.bind(obj.objectId);
    // if( a == ""  )
    if( this.getCookiefunc('RahlTradingProductID-' + obj.objectId) == "")
      {
        //create the cookie
        document.cookie="RahlTradingProductID-" + obj.objectId + "=true; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2017 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
          //update state
          if(obj.objectId == "FTWVeyCc4o")
            {
              this.setState({FTWVeyCc4o:true});
              this.setState({number_ofItems: this.state.number_ofItems + 1});


            }
          else if(obj.objectId == "aJ3DoJp352")
            {
              this.setState({aJ3DoJp352:true});
              this.setState({number_ofItems: this.state.number_ofItems + 1});
            }
          else if(obj.objectId == "dgeRhSG21U")
            {
              this.setState({dgeRhSG21U:true});
              this.setState({number_ofItems: this.state.number_ofItems + 1});
            }
      }
    else
      {//alert("Delete Cookie")
        //delete the cookie
        document.cookie="RahlTradingProductID-" + obj.objectId + "=; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2000 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";

        if(obj.objectId == "FTWVeyCc4o")
          {
            this.setState({FTWVeyCc4o:false});
            this.setState({number_ofItems: this.state.number_ofItems - 1});
          }
        else if(obj.objectId == "aJ3DoJp352")
          {
            this.setState({aJ3DoJp352:false});
            this.setState({number_ofItems: this.state.number_ofItems - 1});
          }
        else if(obj.objectId == "dgeRhSG21U")
          {
            this.setState({dgeRhSG21U:false});
            this.setState({number_ofItems: this.state.number_ofItems - 1});
          }

      }

  },

  noOfItemsAdded:function(){

  counter= 0;
    if(this.state.FTWVeyCc4o)
    counter = counter +1;
      if(this.state.aJ3DoJp352)
      counter = counter +1;
        if(this.state.dgeRhSG21U)
        counter = counter +1;
      this.setState({number_ofItems: counter});
      //alert(counter);
  },


  getCookiefunc:function(cname){
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
  }

});

module.exports = Catalog;
```

And here is my AppWrapper.jsx

```js
var React = require('react');

var Catalog = require('./Catalog');
// var cart = require('./cart');


var contents = [
  <Catalog onIncrementCount={this.onIncrementCount}/>
  // ,<cart />
];



var AppWrapper = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      currentTab: 0,
      count: 0
    };
  },

  onIncrementCount: function() {
      this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1});
alert(this.state.count)
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
<div>
      <div className="site-wrapper">

        <div className="site-wrapper-inner">

          <div className="cover-container">



              <div className="masthead clearfix">
                  <div className="inner">
                      <h3 className="masthead-brand">
                          <img src="images/naleczowianka-logo.png" />
                      </h3>

                      <nav>
                          <ul className="nav masthead-nav">
                              <li className="active"><a href="#" >English  <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span></a></li>
                              <li><a href="#"><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>&nbsp; Login</a></li>

                          </ul>
                    </nav>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <br />

              <div className="inner cover">

                  <header className="row">
                      <div className="col-md-12">

                          <div className="row">
                              <div className="col-md-4 col-xs-4"><h4 className="active">Choose Product</h4></div>

                              <div className="col-md-4 col-xs-4"><h4>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"> </span>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </a>
                                <a href="http://www.google.com" className="NavLinks"  >Shopping Cart ( {this.state.count} ) </a>
                              </h4></div>
                              <div className="col-md-4 col-xs-4"><h4>Order</h4></div>
                          </div>


                          <br />

                          <div className="progress">
                              <div className="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active width-15" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" >
                                    <span className="sr-only">15% Complete</span>
                              </div>
                          </div>

                      </div>
                  </header>

                  <br />

                  <main className="row box">

                      <div className="col-md-12">


                      <div className="row">


                        <div >
                         {contents[this.state.currentTab] }
                        </div>


                      <br />

                      <div className="row">

                          <div className="col-md-6">
                              <h4>Still Waters</h4>
                              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
                          </div>

                          <div className="col-md-6">
                              <h4>Sparkling Waters</h4>
                              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      </div>

                      </div>
                      </main>

                      <div className="mastfoot">
                      <div className="inner row">

                      <div className="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                      <a href="">Rahl Trading</a>
                      </div>

                      <div className="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                      <a href="">Frequently Asked Questions</a>
                      </div>

                      <div className="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                      <a href="">Privacy</a>
                      </div>

                      </div>
                      </div>

                      </div>

                      </div>

                      </div>
                      </div>
                      </div>

    

    );
  },

  selectTab: function(tab) {
    this.setState({ currentTab: tab });
    //  this.props.tabChanged(tab);
  }
});

module.exports = AppWrapper;
```

Answer (score 1):

In React, you will usually pass data back to the parent by using callbacks as props. Something like this:

```
var Child = React.createClass({
    getDefaultProps: function() {
        return {
            onIncrementCount: null
        };
    },

    render: function() {
        return <button onClick={this.incrementCount}>Increment</button>;
    },

    incrementCount: function() {
         // Some data you want to pass externally
         var data = [1,2,3];
         this.props.onIncrementCount.call(this, data);
    }
});

var Parent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child onIncrementCount={this.onIncrementCount} />
                <div>Count is {this.state.count}</div>
            </div>
        );
    },

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            count: 0 
        };
    },

    onIncrementCount: function() {
        this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1});
    }
});
```

The child takes the callback `onIncrementCount`, and the parent passes in its own local function as the callback. The child can then trigger this callback.

Edit:
In regards to your new information, in your `ProductButtonClicked` function, you need to store the `number_ofItems` in a local variable, then assign setState at the end of your function. So instead of calling `setState`, assign it in a similar fashion to this:

```
var number_ofItems;
if( this.getCookiefunc('RahlTradingProductID-' + obj.objectId) == "")
    // Your usual logic here, but set the local variable
    number_ofItems = this.state.number_ofItems -  1;
}

// End of your function
this.setState({number_ofItems: number_ofItems});

// Send the data to the parent
this.props.incrementCount(number_ofItems);
```

However, in your parent function, you need to pass in the incrementCount function as props to the Catalog when it's rendered.

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
    render: function() { 
         return <Catalog incrementCount={this.incrementCount} />;
    },

    incrementCount: function(newCount) {
        // Finally you can use your newCount here, which was from the child
    }
})
```

Comment: I tried it, it did not work in my case because I use 'Tabs'. Can you help in this? I put it in JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6wjw9z1y/

Comment: Ok now that I have a clearer understanding of your use case, you can get rid of the `incrementCount` method, since you already know where you set your _tab_ value (inside your `selectTab` method). You can set the state of the current tab here, then broadcast it outside using a callback e.g. right after `setState`, call something like `this.props.tabChanged(tab)`

Comment: I really appreciate your help. But I did not get what you mean. Note: In your last comment, you assumed I need to send the value of the Tab number, not true. But I am actually going to send another value. I updated the code above for you to understand it easily.. I am confident you will get and solve it..thanks

Comment: It is a little more clear but I'm still not sure when you need to send the data back, and what exactly is the data you want to send back. Is the data sent back whenever the tab changes? On clicks?

Comment: I said I need to send the number_ofItems back from the function ProductButtonClicked.

Comment: Not related to tab change